# Check within Jenkinsfile if docker service exists

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I am setting up an CI Pipelin by means of Jenkins.

I created the following Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
agent none

stages {
    stage('Build and push image') {
        agent {
                label 'man'
              }
        steps {
            sh 'docker image build -t login:stage .'
            sh 'docker tag login:stage 192.168.66.201:5000/login:stage'
            sh 'docker push 192.168.66.201:5000/login:stage'
        }
    }
    stage('Create Service') {
        agent {
                label 'dev'
              }
        steps {
            sh 'docker service create --name loginService -p 40001:40001 --replicas=3  192.168.66.201:5000/login:stage'
        }
    }
} 
}
```

I know, I could use the components of docker (docker.withRegistry) but I like to do it manually in first attempt to exactly knew what happens.

But my question is how to check in the "Create Service"-Stage, if a docker service already exists. If he exists I like to execute an update statement.

You've got any idea? Using google or jenkins docs did not really helped me..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way for doing this:

```
docker service ls | grep <service-name> && echo service-exists
```

If the service with name  exists, the echo will execute. Replace the echo with the update command you intend to use.

Comment: the answer of the scripts is unfortunately ambiguous. if my service is "my-container", and I am enter `docker service ls | grep my && echo service-exists` the script would echo "service-exists".

Answer (score 1):

Another way to check if service already exists is to use inspect command and look at the exit code

```
def inspectExitCode = sh script: "docker service inspect loginService", returnStatus: true
if (inspectExitCode == 0) {
    sh "docker service update --name loginService ... "
} else {
    sh script: "docker service create --name loginService ... "
}
```

In this case you won't run into the issue that was mentioned by @volker-schukai